# Dot net MAUI Android emulator integrating Web API

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, maui, maui-android

[Sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHKBc.png)

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

I tried to connect with middleware to integrating Web API and MAUI and I got Reference issue and Runtime package missing issue.

I'm expecting that the Web API to connect with MAUI android emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the below file (network_security_config.xml) within the Resources/xml directory of your Android project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**Cleartext Traffic Permitted** : By setting cleartextTrafficPermitted="true", your app can make unencrypted HTTP requests. While useful for development, it's recommended to switch to HTTPS for production to ensure data security.

**Trust Anchors** : The  section with  means your app trusts the system's pre-installed CA certificates. This doesn't directly address trusting self-signed certificates but ensures that certificates from recognized CAs are trusted.

To use this configuration in a .NET MAUI Android application, you need to reference it in your Android manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) like so:

```
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
    ...
</application>
```

**Implementing IHttpHelper Interface in C#**

The IHttpHelper interface and its implementation HttpHelper allow you to customize how your application handles SSL certificate validation.

```
public interface IHttpHelper
    {
        HttpClientHandler GetInsecureHandler();
    }

    public class HttpHelper : IHttpHelper
    {
        public HttpClientHandler GetInsecureHandler()
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) =>
            {
                if (cert.Issuer.Equals("CN=localhost"))
                    return true;
                return errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None;
            };
            return handler;
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
var httpHelper = new HttpHelper();
var handler = httpHelper.GetInsecureHandler();
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

**Also note that** :

*The correct address to use when trying to access your local development server from an Android emulator is 10.0.2.2.*