# send a client side request to a asp.net api using maui blazor hybrid push an error : connexion failure

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, maui, maui-blazor

i want to send an image that i take using a mobile app to the server side using maui blazor hybrid but it gives me an error
i use my phone to execute the mobile app , the adresse 192.168.1.5 is the ip adress of my computer where i execute my api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFOwL.jpg)

this is the client side code

```
 <button @onclick="@IncrementCount" class="text-center camera-button p-3 px-5 text-white">
         Scan
     </button>
 </div>
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private async void IncrementCount()
    {
        FileResult? photo=null;
        if (DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android || DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        {
            photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
        }
        if (photo == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            var dotnetImageStream = new DotNetStreamReference(stream);
            string apiUrl = "http://192.168.1.5:5025/api/Main/upload";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            using (var imageContent = new StreamContent(dotnetImageStream.Stream))
            {
                // Add the image content to the request
                content.Add(imageContent, "image", "image.jpg");
                try{
                // Make the HTTP POST request
                var response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);

                // Check if the request was successful
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                        await Swal.FireAsync("Oops...", $"HTTP request failed: {response.IsSuccessStatusCode}", "success");

                    // Image successfully uploaded
                    // You can handle the response if needed
                }
                else
                {
                        await Swal.FireAsync("Oops...", $"HTTP request failed: {response.IsSuccessStatusCode}", "success");

                    // Handle the error (e.g., log or display a message)
                   // await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
                }
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                {
                    await Swal.FireAsync("Oops...", $"HTTP request failed: {ex.Message}", "success");
                    // Log or display more information about the exception
                    // await DisplayAlert("Error", $"HTTP request failed: {ex.Message}", "OK");
                }
            }
        }
            // this is the image stream
            // do what you want here
            // // DisplayImageMessageBox(dotnetImageStream);
        } 
    }
```

this the MauiProgram.cs file

```
using CurrieTechnologies.Razor.SweetAlert2;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DEMOAPP
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                });

            builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();

#if DEBUG
            builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
            builder.Services.AddSweetAlert2();
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the api  program.cs file

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowOriginPolicy", builder =>
    {
     builder.AllowAnyOrigin() // Replace with your Angular app's origin
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("AllowOriginPolicy");


app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

this is the controller file maiccontroller.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace demoappapi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MainController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("upload")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(IFormFile image)
        {
            try
            {
                if (image == null || image.Length == 0)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Invalid image file");
                }

                // Process the image (e.g., save to disk, store in a database, etc.)
                var imagePath = Path.Combine("wwwroot", "images", image.FileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await image.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }

                // You can perform additional processing here based on your requirements

                return Ok("Image uploaded successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exceptions appropriately
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you use **physical** device for debugging, ensure that your mobile device and your computer are on the same network. Try to reach the IP address '192.168.1.5' from your mobile device through a web browser. If it is not reachable from mobile device, try to find the ip address of the mobile device and host the Web API temporary for debugging there.
- If you use **emulator** check this out : [Dot net MAUI Android emulator integrating Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77913175/dot-net-maui-android-emulator-integrating-web-api/77913503#77913503).